# updating Application Packaging Standard(APS) in plesk

Tags: plesk

I am trying to install an app on parallels plesk panel 11.0.9. I opened the app folder and then edited in the APP-META.xml file I edited the app configuration. After that I updated the APP-LIST.xml and tried to upload the file to the panel, but when I did that I got this error:

```
Error: The app could not be added: Failed to find APP-META.xml in archive /tmp/test.app.zip. (Empty error message).
```

I am sure that APP-META.xml exists what I am missing ?? 
Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your archive has root folder:

```
/some_folder_name
/some_folder_name/APP-META.xml
/some_folder_name/ ... other files here ...
```

whereas it should be in root of archive:

```
/APP-META.xml
/... other files here ...
```